# Matlab - Help using text scan, how to ignore comments and header columns?

Tags: matlab, textscan, textreader, csv

I need help using text scan. I am trying to read data that has the following format:

```
# ---------------------------------- WARNING ----------------------------------------
# The data you have obtained from this automated U.S. Geological Survey database
# have not received Director's approval and as such are provisional and subject to
# revision.  The data are released on the condition that neither the USGS nor the
# United States Government may be held liable for any damages resulting from its use.
# Additional info: http://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/help/?provisional
#
# File-format description:  http://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/?tab_delimited_format_info
# Automated-retrieval info: http://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/?automated_retrieval_info
#
# Contact:   gs-w_support_nwisweb@usgs.gov
# retrieved: 2013-09-13 13:10:29 EDT       (nadww01)
#
# Data for the following 1 site(s) are contained in this file
#    USGS 08067074 CWA Canal at Thompson Rd nr Baytown, TX
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Data provided for site 08067074
#    DD parameter   Description
#    01   00010     Temperature, water, degrees Celsius
#    02   00095     Specific conductance, water, unfiltered, microsiemens per centimeter at 25 degrees Celsius
#
# Data-value qualification codes included in this output: 
#     A  Approved for publication -- Processing and review completed.  
#     P  Provisional data subject to revision.  
# 
agency_cd   site_no datetime    tz_cd   01_00010    01_00010_cd 02_00095    02_00095_cd
5s  15s 20d 6s  14n 10s 14n 10s
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 00:00    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 00:15    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 00:30    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 00:45    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 01:00    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 01:15    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 01:30    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 01:45    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 02:00    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 02:15    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 02:30    CST 10.3    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 02:45    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 03:00    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 03:15    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 03:30    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 03:45    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 04:00    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 04:15    CST 10.2    A   392 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 04:30    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 04:45    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 05:00    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 05:15    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 05:30    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 05:45    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 06:00    CST 10.2    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 06:15    CST 10.1    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 06:30    CST 10.1    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 06:45    CST 10.1    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 07:00    CST 10.1    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 07:15    CST 10.1    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 07:30    CST 10.1    A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 07:45    CST 10.0    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 08:00    CST 10.0    A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 08:15    CST 10.0    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 08:30    CST 10.0    A   391 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 08:45    CST 10.0    A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 09:00    CST 10.0    A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 09:15    CST 10  A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 09:30    CST 10  A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 09:45    CST 10  A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 10:00    CST 10  A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 10:15    CST 10  A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 10:30    CST 10  A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 10:45    CST 10  A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 11:00    CST 10  A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 11:15    CST 10  A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 11:30    CST 10  A   390 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 11:45    CST 10  A   389 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 12:00    CST 10  A   389 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 12:15    CST 10  A   389 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 12:30    CST 10  A   389 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 12:45    CST 10  A   389 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 13:00    CST 10  A   389 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 13:15    CST 10  A   389 A
USGS    08067074    2013-01-05 13:30    CST 10  A   389 A
```

The only two data entries I am concerned with are "Specific conductance", and "date". (columns 3 and 7 respectively)

I was able to do this on a consistant basis using the following code:

```
%% 
% Collect conductance data
filename = 'conductivityData_Temp_File';


%%
% Determine length of data file 
fid = fopen('conductivityData_Temp_File','r');
fseek(fid, 0, 'eof');
chunksize = ftell(fid);
fseek(fid, 0, 'bof');
ch = fread(fid, chunksize, '*uchar');
N = sum(ch == sprintf('\n')); % number of lines
fclose(fid)

%% 
% Read conductivity data
fileconductID = fopen(filename);
waterConductivityData = textscan(fileconductID, '%s %d %s %s %f %s %f %s', N, 'delimiter', '\t', 'EmptyValue', 0, 'headerlines', 27);
fclose(fileconductID);
```

However, I found out that you can simply use 'commentstyle' to ignore the comments. This is important because I am reading multiple files and occasionally I will encounter a file that does not have exactly 27 comment rows. That will make my program throw an error.

Can someone tell me how I can adjust my textscan code to ignore the comment rows and skip the two header rows?

I apologize if the example code I supplied is complicated but basically my error resides in this one line of code:

```
waterConductivityData = textscan(fileconductID, '%s %d %s %s %f %s %f %s', N, 'delimiter', '\t', 'EmptyValue', 0, 'headerlines', 27);
```

(if you want to downlad an example tab deliminated file to work with use this link:  [here](http://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/usa/nwis/uv/?cb_00095=on&cb_00010=on&format=rdb&period=360&begin_date=&end_date=&site_no=08067074)

Thank you!

ANSWER:

---

Thank you TryHard, that was a good approach but i wanted to stay closer to what i was doing previously. Apparently my Delimiters were off.

```
waterConductivityData = textscan(fileconductID,'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s ' , 'Delimiter', '\t', 'CommentStyle', '#');

dates = waterConductivityData{3}(3:end);
conductancesStr = waterConductivityData{7}(3:end);
temperaturesStr = waterConductivityData{5}(3:end);

conductances = str2double(conductancesStr);
temperatures = str2double(temperaturesStr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your textscan line to this:

```
waterConductivityData = textscan(fileconductID, '%s %d %s %s %f %s %f %s', N, 'Delimiter', '\t', 'EmptyValue', 0, 'CommentStyle', '#');
```

And then get the columns you wanted like this:

```
dates = waterConductivityData{3}(3:end)
conductances = waterConductivityData{7}(3:end)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am asking, but your answer doesn't work the way I expected.  It only returns:                                                                                                                                 'agency_cd' [] [] [] [] [] [] []

Comment: Oh, I just assumed the formatSpec was working. Hold on and I'll actually throw it into Matlab.

Comment: I edited my initial answer. Let me know if that's still not the output you were expecting.

Comment: This worked after I changed the delimiters. I also did away with 'N'

Answer (score 0):

One way to circumvent variable header length is to parse the file as follows:

```
fid=fopen(file);
str=textscan(fid,'%s')
fclose(fid)

str2=strvcat(str{1});
fst=strmatch('CST',str2);

dtstr = str2(fst(1)-2:9:end,:);   % date strings
timstr = str2(fst(1)-1:9:end,:);  % time strings
condctv = str2(fst(1)+3:9:end,:); % conductivity string
```

This finds the first occurrence of string "CST" and parses assuming the data lines to be organized similarly in all files, and it requires "CST" to occur in the first data row of the table. If that is not a constant in your data files then the idea is a bust. However you might be able to use other strings to chart your way through the data table, assuming they are unique and always show up in the same place. The following makes use of the last format specifier in the format string:

```
str2=strvcat(str{1});
fst=strmatch('10s',str2);
fst=fst(end);

dtstr = str2(fst+3:9:end,:);
timstr = str2(fst+4:9:end,:);
condctv = str2(fst+8:9:end,:);
```

You can convert the strings in `condctv` into numeric data with `str2num`, as follows:

```
condctv = str2num(conductv);
```

Comment: This seems to only work is 'cst" is in the file.  I have been trying to get it to work by finding 'USGS' instead, since this occurs in every file.  The other issue is that i need to have the data in arrays not as vertically concatenated strings.

Comment: @JohnAugust Using USGS is a little more risky because it shows up in the comments. On the other hand you could look for the last occurrence of a comment marker #, but this is almost the same as the alternate answer - I can modify the answer to use # if you prefer(or you can figure it out :). The data can easily be converted and placed in a matrix. For instance str2num(condctv) returns a column vector with the conductivities.